# Can I use taxonomy term as relationship in view?

Tags: views

I created a content type called 'Job' in which I added:

- a 'Company name' field of term reference type
- a vocabulary 'Organizations' containing company names as terms

I want to create a view of nodes of type 'Job' in which I want to display the email of the user who have created it?

How can I do so?

**Notes**:

- When I try to create a relationship using the company name field, it does not show user email in fields and when I use author as relationship its showing?
- I have both relationships (ie relationship on user + relationship on taxonomy term), but is it possible to use only one i.e company name?
- I have created 'company page' as content type containing email id and user reference field so it can relate to this?

Comment: Please check the various "notes" I added, I mostly copy/paste-ed them from your various comments below the existing answer. Those kinds of extra details really belong in your question. Feel free to rephrase, extend, whatever where needed. If you don't like them at all, just rollback to a prior version of this question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of `jobs`:

[image]

with a taxonomy term relationship on your `field_company_name` in order to show the taxonomy term name and any other fields it might have.

In order to show the email of user that is referenced from the taxonomy term you will also need a relationship (via the field_company_name relationship) on `user` so that you can access the user fields (eg email). The option to add this relationship will now be available from the relationships list, if you filter by user.

[image]

---

Sidenote: You may want to consider using an additional email address on the user for this in case the user does not want to receive job applications at their own personal email address, but wants to use their personal email address to manage the account.

Comment: thanks, but whenever i am trying to create relationship using company name field it does not show user email in fields and whenever i am using author as relationship its showing??

Comment: do you have both relationships? (ie relationship on user + relationship on taxonomy term) You will need both in order to show both user (author) email and company name

Comment: yes i have but is it possible to use only one i.e company name??

Comment: no. you need information from both the user and term that are related to your 'job'. Is this a problem?

Comment: actually no but i have created 'company page' as content type containing email id and user reference field so it can relate to this??

Comment: ah - i see, the user is related to company page, not to job. yes you can create a relationship on a relationship, eg once you have created taxonomy relationship there will be the option to create a user relationship via that

Comment: but its not working for me

Comment: to do this do i need to use textfield as company name??

Comment: no, give me a sec to provide example

Comment: I have edited your question to reflect the detail you have given in comments, hope is accurate

Comment: looks like Pierre got there first, think may have overwritten :)